# PostgreSQL trigger on multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am working on a project which requires moving data among multiple "stages" (a concept in this project) in PostgreSQL.

To simplify the problem, let's say we have two stages (stage 1 and 2), and there are three tables `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` in stage 1, and their contents need to be copied to stage 2 when updated.

The requirement is, the contents of these tables should be copied (by `INSERT`) to stage 2 only when they are **all** updated in stage 1.

To fulfil this requirement, I was thinking about using triggers, but it seems that triggers only work for one table, as I read from [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/introduction-postgresql-trigger/):

```
A PostgreSQL trigger is a function invoked automatically whenever an event associated with a table occurs.
```

So, are there any other mechanisms to achieve this?

Comment: Traditional triggers won't take care of this.  You could consider a stored procedure that could be called by triggers on the three tables and would not do anything if the three tables are not "done".  Alternatively, you could externalize this logic in a programming language.  Lastly, this isn't a great use of a database and some other architecture could be used.  But some code needs to be written to handle this.

Comment: Hi, you can use this website(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) to write your table script.